# It is possible to figure out which internet connection is correlated with which networkInterface?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I am a noob in netoworks stuff, but I must to get to know something.

When I have list o networkInterface

```
rmnet0
eth0
lo
//etc.
```

How can I tell, which kind of connection (wifi/bluethoof/UMTS) use which networkInterface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command 'lshal'